# Install and setup java JDK from Oracle

Tags: 16.04, java, jdk, oracle

Trying to understand what and why should be done while installing `JDK 9` from `Oracle` from fresh. I have downloaded archive `jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`. I found that this archive contains whole java directory structure, but no installer. What I should do next? Is it right to place java into `/usr/local/`.

I suppose I need to tell system where java is located by setting path. Where is the right place to tell standard `Ubuntu 16.04` system about that?

I know that I should set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable by setting whole path to java home directory. Where I can do that?

What else I should do in order to get fully working system?

Comment: Please don't duplicate close vote this question to an unfocused generic question. While this issue is not uniquely restricted to only the jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz file, it is specific to some Oracle Java archives, not all Java archives.